# Extract column value based on another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am kind of getting stuck on extracting value of one variable conditioning on another variable. For example, the following dataframe:

```
A  B
p1 1
p1 2
p3 3
p2 4
```

How can I get the value of `A` when `B=3`? Every time when I extracted the value of `A`, I got an object, not a string.

Comment: I see, I should add `item()` at the end.

Comment: `df.query` and `pd.eval` seem like good fits for this use case. For information on the `pd.eval()` family of functions, their features and use cases, please visit [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval).

Answer (score 382, accepted):

You could use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to get series which satisfying your condition and then [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to get first element:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
    A  B
0  p1  1
1  p1  2
2  p3  3
3  p2  4

In [3]: df.loc[df['B'] == 3, 'A']
Out[3]:
2    p3
Name: A, dtype: object

In [4]: df.loc[df['B'] == 3, 'A'].iloc[0]
Out[4]: 'p3'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. `df.loc[df['B'] == 3, 'A'].item()` works for me too.

Comment: which one does it pick if the data frame has multiple entries of '3' in column B?

Comment: df.loc[df["Condition_Column"] == 0, ("Column_1", "Column_2, "Column_3", "Column_4")] works for me. This example for select multiple columns. They should be in tuple.

Comment: if the df.loc[df['B'] == 300, 'A'].iloc[0]   means what will be the output?

Comment: .item() apparently has been deprecated and will be removed. Is there another way to do this? I'm not interested in the name of the column or datatype which is also returned with the .loc method to query.

Comment: Another alternative to the .iloc[0] part at the end is .iat[0] which also just returns the first element but has slightly less overhead than .iloc.

Comment: @user1999109 if the condition doesn't have any matches (in your example, 300 is never found in column B), then the part before .iloc will return an empty series. If you then try to  retrieve a value at a non-existent index (index 0), it returns an IndexError.

Comment: @andersonzhu What if there are two columns (example column C with similar values as B0? `df.loc[df['B'] == 3 && df['C'] == 6, 'A'].item()` doesn't work

Comment: @Sulphur you need to wrap the sub-statements with `()`. `df.loc[(df['B'] == 3) & (df['C'] == 6), 'A'].item()` should work.

Comment: I wonder if this creates one intermediate `DataFrame` when it evaluates the expression `df['B'] == 3` or if it evaluates `loc` lazily.

Comment: Great answer! I was able to extend this in some code I'm writing to `df = df[df.column1 != df.loc[df['column2'] == 0, 'column1'].iloc[0]]`, which for me, finds a bad item in column2, and removes all rows that have a match in column1.

Comment: When I'm using the suggested code df.loc[df['B'] == 3, 'A'].iloc[0], I'm only getting one value, since we are doing .iloc[0]. However, in my dataframe, I have multiple records for the same condition. How can I get all the values returned?

Comment: Can this be used in a .fillna() function?

df.loc[df['B'] == 3, 'A'].iloc[0]

Comment: @ssuhas76 sure, in case `df.loc[df['B'] == 3, 'A'].iloc[0] is a hashable value (float, int, string, set) it can be used for `fillna`.

Answer (score 90):

You can try `query`, which is less typing:

```
df.query('B==3')['A']
```

Comment: Query is interesting cause we can add more complex clauses to it as well

Comment: IMHO, this is the best answer.

Comment: @NLR It depends. `query` creates a new `DataFrame`, and then the slice `['A']` creates yet another `DataFrame`. For large cases one would like to avoid the unnecessary intermediate object.

Answer (score 62):

Try:

```py
df[df['B']==3]['A'].item()
```

assuming `df` is your `pandas.DataFrame`.

Comment: Can you please give a link where exactly this method is described in pandas official documentation?

Comment: I mean `][` part.

Comment: @vasili111 check pandas filter

Comment: Add a .item() in the end.

Answer (score 23):

Use `df[df['B']==3]['A'].values[0]` if you just want item itself without the brackets

Comment: Can you please give a link where exactly this method is described in pandas official documentation? I mean `][` part.

Comment: It does return the result with []

Comment: You still need to put `[0]` at the end to access the value.

Answer (score 15):

**Edited**:  What I described below under Previous is chained indexing and may not work in some situations.  The best practice is to use loc, but the concept is the same:

```
df.loc[row, col]
```

*row* and *col* can be specified directly (e.g., 'A' or ['A', 'B']) or with a mask (e.g. df['B'] == 3).  Using the example below:

```
df.loc[df['B'] == 3, 'A']
```

**Previous**:  It's easier for me to think in these terms, but borrowing from other answers.  The value you want is located in a dataframe:

```
df[*column*][*row*]
```

where *column* and *row* point to the values you want returned.  For your example, *column* is 'A' and for *row* you use a mask:

```
df['B'] == 3
```

To get the first matched value from the series there are several options:

```
df['A'][df['B'] == 3].values[0]
df['A'][df['B'] == 3].iloc[0]
df['A'][df['B'] == 3].to_numpy()[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.squeeze.html#pandas.Series.squeeze) instead of `iloc[0]`. It looks clearer if you have only one value:

```
df.loc[df['B'] == 3, 'A'].squeeze()
```

Output:

```
'p3'
```

Answer (score 1):

`````
df.loc[df['B']=='give-specific-value', 'A']````

I have also worked on this clausing and extraction operations for my assignment.
`````