# get column value based on another column with list of strings in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiple-columns

I tried the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684013/extract-column-value-based-on-another-column-pandas-dataframe). But it doesnt work for my example given below.
I tried the loc[0] for the output. I tried .item(). But none of these help me.

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Item':['[Phone]', '[Watch]', '[Pen]', '[Pencil]', '[Knife]'], 'RelatedItem': ['[Phone cover]', '[Watch strap]', '[Pen cap]', '[Pencil lead]', '[fork]'], 'CountinInventory':['20','50','40','80','90']})
>>> df2
    Item     RelatedItem   CountinInventory
0   [Phone]  [Phone cover]               20
1   [Watch]  [Watch strap]               50
2     [Pen]      [Pen cap]               40
3  [Pencil]  [Pencil lead]               80
4   [Knife]         [fork]               90
>>> df2.loc[df2['Item'] == 'Phone', 'RelatedItem']
Series([], Name: RelatedItem, dtype: object)
>>> df2.loc[df2['Item'] == 'Phone', 'RelatedItem', 'CountinInventory']
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

I have this data where when I feed `Phone`, I need to get `Phone cover` along with the `CountinInventory` value as my answer. Please advice what mistake am I doing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need `str` for remove first and last `[]` or use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
mask = df2['Item'].str[1:-1] == 'Phone'
#alternative solution
#mask = df2['Item'].str.strip('[]') == 'Phone'

print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: Item, dtype: bool
```

If no missing values is possible use `list comprehension`, what is faster if large data:

```
mask = [x[1:-1] == 'Phone'for x in df2['Item']]

mask = [x.strip('[]') == 'Phone'for x in df2['Item']]
print (mask)

[True, False, False, False, False]
```

Last for select multiple columns use `list`:

```
df3 = df2.loc[mask, ['RelatedItem', 'CountinInventory']]
print (df3)
     RelatedItem CountinInventory
0  [Phone cover]               20
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But if I a webpage will send in an api request with the Item name and I need to return the 'RelatedItem' and 'CountinInventory' then the mask based option wouldn't be a good one right? I am curious. Do you think just returning the output values like 'Phone cover' and '20' alone is possible

Comment: @Sudhi - Do you think `print (df3.to_string(index=False, header=None))` ?

Comment: Cool this seems to return only the necessary output values. perfect. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sudhi - And also if want return first matched value `print (next(iter(df3['RelatedItem']), 'no match'))
print (next(iter(df3['CountinInventory']), 'no match'))`

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you one question? I am trying to get a user input like `name = input('Write Item Name of your choice -')`. But I am unable to pass the input as string inside `next(iter(df3[name]), 'no match'))` to get the other to column values that I am interested in. Any suggestions

Comment: @Sudhi It should working nice, if use `name = 'Item'` it nor working? Now I am offline, on phone only, so cannot tested.

Comment: no worries. Thanks for responding. I shall try to figure out myself. Else will ask new question

Comment: what was problem?

Comment: I made mistake in the way the string input was being used. I had to add single quotes before I passed into the script to get the other columns I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
df.loc[df['Item'].str.contains('Phone'), ['RelatedItem',  'CountinInventory']]
```

The error `too many indexers` is because df.loc[] expects an array of labels, list or slice object with labels. But you have given a sequence of 'labels'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can we just print or output the values alone. I mean I don't need the headings like 'Item' or 'RelatedItem'

Comment: I guess @jezrael has answered your question.