# How to find row with specific column value only

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to figure out the names who only have specific column value and nothing else.

I have tried filtering the rows according to the column value but that isn't what I want, I want the names who only went to eat pizza.

I want names who only had pizza, so my code should return John only and not peter as john only had pizza

[Click to view data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXuv8.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extract column value based on another column pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684013/extract-column-value-based-on-another-column-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Try: `df.loc[df['Restaurant'] == 'pizza', 'Name']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Comment: @MohitMotwani: I don't think it a dup of the link you posted. He only wants `John`, yours will show all names having `Restaurant` of `pizza`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is not clear. At first, it looks like a simple `.loc` will be enough. However, after viewing your picture of sample data, I realized it is not that simple. To get what you want, you need to identify duplicated or non-duplicated `names` having one `Restaurant` value only, and pick it. To do this, you need to use `nunique` and check it `eq(1)`, and assign it a mask `m`. Finally, using `m` with slicing to get your desire output:

Your sample data:

```
In [512]: df
Out[512]:
    Name    Restaurant
0   john  pizza
1  peter    kfc
2   john  pizza
3  peter  pizza
4  peter    kfc
5  peter  pizza
6   john  pizza

m = df.groupby('Name').Restaurant.transform('nunique').eq(1)
df[m]

Out[513]:
   Name    Res
0  john  pizza
2  john  pizza
6  john  pizza
```

If you want to show only one row, just chain additional `.drop_duplicates`

```
df[m].drop_duplicates()

Out[515]:
   Name    Restaurant
0  john  pizza
```