# Creating dictionary of parent child pairs in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns as:

```
CHILD   PARENT
1       2
2       3
3       4
10      11
11      12
```

I need to create a dictionary where I keep the top parent as key and all its descendents as set of values, like:

```
4: [1,2,3]
12: [10,11]
```

I have been able to extract 12 and 4 as top parents from this dataframe, by code from following link:

[extract column value based on another column pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684013/extract-column-value-based-on-another-column-pandas-dataframe/36685531)

Now, I have no idea how to do this in python. In java I can do this by following a dfs. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can only think of using networkx as pandas isn't cut out for data structures to be specific. You can construct a graph from this relationship and then, from there, all you need is finding various subgraphs that are disconnected with each other.

Comment: The graphs are guaranteed to be acyclic? And can a node be a descendant of more than one parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way from `networkx`

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'CHILD', 'PARENT')
l=list(nx.connected_components(G))
L=[dict.fromkeys(y,x) for x, y in enumerate(l)]
d={k: v for d in L for k, v in d.items()}
df.groupby(df.CHILD.map(d)).agg({'CHILD':'unique','PARENT':'max'})
Out[328]: 
       PARENT      CHILD
CHILD                   
0           4  [1, 2, 3]
1          12   [10, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a BFS approach *not* based on `networkx` which is a great Python package, though not part of [the Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/).

**Code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [10, 11], [11, 12]],
                  columns=['CHILD', 'PARENT'])

# build graph
graph = defaultdict(set)
for child, parent in df[['CHILD', 'PARENT']].values:
    graph[parent].add(child)

# identity root nodes
roots = []
for node in graph.keys():
    if all(node not in children for children in graph.values()):
        roots.append(node)

# find the descendents of each root node
result = {}
for root in roots:
    visited = set()
    unvisited = graph[root]
    while unvisited:
        visited |= unvisited
        unvisited = set.union(*(graph[node] for node in unvisited)) - visited
    result[root] = visited

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{4: {1, 2, 3}, 12: {10, 11}}
```