# Pandas - Get value based on minimum value in other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
      Q        GDP  
248 2008q3  14891.6 
249 2008q4  14577.0 
250 2009q1  14375.0 
251 2009q2  14355.6
```

I want to the value for Q where GDP is lowest.

Based on this post,[extract column value based on another column pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684013/extract-column-value-based-on-another-column-pandas-dataframe), I tried the following:

```
    df = df.loc[df['GDP'].min(),'Quarters'].iloc[0]
```

However I got this following error msg:

```
    TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [14355.6] of <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This:

```
df.loc[df['GDP'].idxmin()]['Q']
```

Output:

```
'2009q2'
```