# How can I get unique values from csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a small question. How can I print all the texts belonging to that author by selecting the author from the csv that I read with the pandas below, can you help with the python code? (ex. I want to display all texts where eap is author.)

Thank you!

```
id      text                                                author
id26305 This process, however, afforded me no means of...   EAP
id17569 It never once occurred to me that the fumbling...   HPL
id11008 In his left hand was a gold snuff box, from wh...   EAP
id27763 How lovely is spring As we looked from Windsor...   MWS
id12958 Finding nothing else, not even gold, the Super...   HPL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey try out using loc()  to get back the series.

```
df.loc[df['author'] == 'EAB', 'text']
```

Also check out this [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684013/extract-column-value-based-on-another-column-pandas-dataframe)