# Iterate over column values matched value based on another column pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a followup to

[extract column value based on another column pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684013/extract-column-value-based-on-another-column-pandas-dataframe)

I have more than one row that matches the column value and want to know how to iterate to efficiently retrieve each value when there are multiple matches.

Dataframe is

```
A  B
p1 1
p1 2
p3 3
p2 4
p4 3
p5 5
p6 2
p7 5
... around 10000 rows
```

The below will always pick p3

```
df.loc[df['B'] == 3, 'A'].iloc[0]
```

So I tried to iterate like

```
 if(len(df.loc[df['B'] == 3, 'A'])) > 1:
                        for i in range(0,len(df.loc[df['B'] == 3, 'A']))-1):
                            print(i,df.loc[df['B'] == 3, 'A'].iloc[i])))
```

And it prints

```
0 p3
1 p4
```

for all matching values

However is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Just use `df.loc[df['B'] == 3, 'A']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all matching values by without using `.iloc[0]` in the `df.loc` code, as follows:

```
df.loc[df['B'] == 3, 'A']
```

Output:

```
2    p3
4    p4
Name: A, dtype: object
```

The `2` `4` on the left of the output are the original row indices.  You can use this information if want to know from which rows are these 2 extracted data originated from.

Comment: Thanks. Now I want to make this interactive, so accepting input from user. I try to compare that by iterating over the df

for i, r in xdf.iteritems():
     if inputvalue == r:
        if(len(df.loc[df['B'] == inputvalue, 'A'])) > 1:
                        for i in range(0,len(df.loc[df['B'] == inputvalue, 'A']))-1):
                            print(i,df.loc[df['B'] == inputvalue, 'A'].iloc[i])))


Output is 
0 p3
0 p3

Comment: @user3423407  Hi, you don't need to write the long loop to achieve the task.  Just substitute your input value to `3` in the code above.  That is, `df.loc[df['B'] == inputvalue, 'A']`

Comment: @user3423407  Your new looping codes doesn't work because you reused the variable `i` in 2 places with different usage.  Thus, the second one is overwriting the first one. That's is, `for i in range(0,len(df.loc[df['B'] == inputvalue, 'A'])-1):`  the `i` here is overwriting the outmost loop `i` in  `for i, r in df.B.iteritems():`.

Comment: @user3423407  You need to change the last 2 lines to use another variable, says `j`:  `for j in range(0,len(df.loc[df['B'] == inputvalue, 'A'])-1): 
                print(i,df.loc[df['B'] == inputvalue, 'A'].iloc[j]) `.   This will give you the expected result of `2 p3
4 p3`

Comment: @user3423407   Although we've fixed the bug of your looping codes, as I said earlier, this loop is not necessary.  Just the code `df.loc[df['B'] == inputvalue, 'A']`  is able to achieve the same result.  Much simplified!

Comment: Understood. Thanks SeaBean

Comment: @user3423407  Welcome!  Pleased to help!   Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `iloc` part and `reset_index` to really get your output:

```
df.loc[df['B'] == 3, 'A'].iloc[0]
                         ^^^^^^^^ Unnecessary
```

```
>>> df.loc[df['B'] == 3, 'A'].reset_index(drop=True)
0    p3
1    p4
Name: A, dtype: object
```